# R simply not running a line of code in a function

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to graph 4 dataframes against each other, and I have narrowed the entirety of the issues I have been having down to one line of code that R is for some reason not running.

```
Compare=function(a,b,c,d){
 d1=a
 d2=b
 d3=c
 d4=d

 for(n in 1:4){
   assign(paste0("colnames",n),colnames(get(paste0("d",n))))
 }
}
```

When I run the line that creates colnames1, colnames2, colnames3, and colnames4, oustide of the function, it works, but if I run it using the function, while d(1:4) are all created as the various dtaframes, the colnames1:4 simply isnt created. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Do not use `assign`. Have your function return the result and assign when you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the global environment in the `assign` function exclusively, if you want to `assign` a variable in a function. Try to run through [this article](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html), and check the code below.

```
assignTest1 = function(){
  assign("val1", 1)
}
assignTest1()
print(val1) # Error in print(val1) : object 'val1' not found

# ----------

assignTest2 = function(){
  assign("val2", 2, globalenv())
}
assignTest2()
print(val2) # [1] 2

# ----------

assignTest3 = function(){
  val3 <- 3 
}
assignTest3()
print(val3) # Error in print(val3) : object 'val3' not found

# ----------

assignTest4 = function(){
  val4 <<- 3
}
assignTest4()
print(val4) # [1] 3
```